# How to install MongoDB compass on Windows 7 32-bit?

Tags: windows, mongodb, 32-bit

I am new to MongoDB. How can I install the MongoDB compass on 32-bit Windows? I have Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit installed.

Apparently the Mongodb compass page does not have a 32-bit version,
I wanted to know if there is a past version that supports 32-bits or an alternative to this application.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: The [Download and Install Compass](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/install) system requirements are quite clear: *64-bit version of Microsoft Windows 7 or later*